# the problem with the listing. nested loops?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am here to open a new line after every 6 from the data that I want to draw the line data.
When the 6-like following code prints the data 36 times.
that this function is checking how many games. If I mention below, but as there are now 36 with 6 printing units. Each one of the prints 6 times.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $db->oyunSayisi(); $i++)
{ 
    if ($i % 6 == 0)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    ?>
    <br/>
    <?php
    foreach($db->oyunCek() as $oyun)
    {
        ?>
        <td width="224" height="115"><a href="<?=$db->siteAdres()?>/oyun.php?id=<?=$oyun['o_id']?>" title="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna"><img height="115;110" src="<?=$db->siteAdres()?>/resimler/<?=$oyun['o_resim']?>" title="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna" alt="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna" /></a></td>
        <?php
    }
    if ($i % 6 == 0)
    {
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How to go down one by one down the line every 6 in the data?

Comment: Let me see if I can rephrase the question: In the data returned from the `oyunSayisi()` function, for every sixth line, you want to output a table row in HTML with data from the `oyunCek()` function?

Comment: maybe say. oyunSayisi()that shows how many games. ((NOW 6 Games))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what may be causing the problem.

For every sixth item returned from `oyunSayisi()`, you want to create a table row that shows the data from `oyunCek()`. The problem is that the first modulus just outputs `<tr>`, then *every* line runs the `foreach` loop. Finally, the second modulus outputs `</tr>`. I think you want to combine everything into just one modulus, like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $db->oyunSayisi(); $i++)
{ 
    if ($i % 6 == 0)
    {
        echo "<tr><br/>\n";
        foreach($db->oyunCek() as $oyun)
        {
            ?>
            <td width="224" height="115"><a href="<?=$db->siteAdres()?>/oyun.php?id=<?=$oyun['o_id']?>" title="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna"><img height="115;110" src="<?=$db->siteAdres()?>/resimler/<?=$oyun['o_resim']?>" title="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna" alt="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna" /></a></td>
            <?php
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Upon further pondering, it did not make sense that you would want to only echo every sixth line of data... so it occurred to me that you are probably trying to create a new table row every sixth line, rather than skipping any of the inner `foreach` loops. Here is the modified code to do that:

```
echo "<tr>\n";
for($i = 0; $i < $db->oyunSayisi(); $i++)
{
    foreach($db->oyunCek() as $oyun)
    {
        ?>
        <td width="224" height="115"><a href="<?=$db->siteAdres()?>/oyun.php?id=<?=$oyun['o_id']?>" title="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna"><img height="115;110" src="<?=$db->siteAdres()?>/resimler/<?=$oyun['o_resim']?>" title="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna" alt="<?=$oyun['o_baslik']?> oyna" /></a></td>
        <?php
    }
    if (($i + 1) % 6 == 0)
    {
        echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: i understand :) $i%6==0 and $i!=0 :)

Comment: In this case, one of 12 must be

Comment: @Yusuf: I ran a sample project and found an error: the `</tr><tr>` should not output on the first item, because `(0 % 6 == 0)` is true. What we want is `((0 + 1) % 6 == 0)`.

Comment: I solved that problem. for example, when 8-game shows on the same line. But 2 of them have to go through the bottom line.